# Base class function of referenced class not exposed in another project

Tags: c#, oop, object

I am using the filter base class of AForge to implement my own filters. So what I do is

```
public sealed class SomeFilter : BaseInPlaceFilter2 { ... }
```

When I create a new instance of the filter in a different project (in this case a console project), the base functions are not exposed, i.e. what I should be able to do is

```
SomeFilter s = new SomeFilter();
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap();
...
s.ApplyInPlace(bmp);
```

The `s.ApplyInPlace(bmp)` is derived from the base class. However, when creating the instance, it is not available.

By trial and error I found, that i need to include AForge in the using-section of the console-project, in addition to the filter class. However, I thought that when I derive from the base class, the base functions and included as well? I think I am not quite understanding the systematic procedure here.

Comment: There is no ApplyInPlace() overload that does not take arguments.  Pretty important that you post code that has at least a *few* odds of giving a repro.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I extended the code bit

Comment: What error does the compiler give you?

Comment: No error at all... it's just that I can't call any function defined in the base class

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Maybe you mean that you don't get IntelliSense when you try to call the method? Does the code compile if you use `s.ApplyInPlace(bmp);`?

Comment: It's correct, I don't get the IntelliSense. It does not compile

Comment: You say "It does not compile". Surely the compiler will give you an error then. What is it?

Comment: Translated into English: The type "BaseInplaceFilter2" is defined in a not-referenced assembly. Add a reference to the assembly "AForge.Imaging, Version...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on error message, you need to include a reference to `AForge.Imaging`.

In general, if Project A references Project B and Project B references Project C, then Project A has to reference Project C if it needs to access types/methods defined in Project C (even if they are exposed only through types defined in Project B).

Comment: Aaah, okay. Is there any way to "decouple" this, so basically for Project A to only refernce Project B?

Comment: @JoeyD, it is the use of inheritance that is causing the coupling. The only way therefore to decouple A from C, is to avoid (publicly exposed) inheritance.